# MySQL Error: "Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" upon Windows 10 PC Restart

Tags: mysql, wordpress, windows-10, mysql-5.5

I installed MySQL 5.5 and provided a password for user 'root'.  I can access it using MySQL Workbench.  The OS that I am using is Windows 10 Home.  Upon restart I am receiving an error:

Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:

```
Access defined for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

and have some errors in my Web Applications such as Wordpress:

```
Error Establishing a Database Connection.
```

Is there a way to access the database and prevent this from happening again.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked to see if the service is running and set to automatic start?

Comment: Yes @P.Salmon, MySQL service is Running and set to Automatic StartupType